# How to manually type a logarithm base on Windows 10/11 in a .txt file

Tags: file, math, text, logarithm

I am currently using a text file to write down some quick notes about searching algorithms and their complexity. To do so, I want to be able to write my notes properly. (for a better understanding)

For instance, I would usually write **log n** of **base 2**.
Instead, I want to write **log₂ n**.

Is their any way to write it on a keyboard without copying and pasting an exemple seen online ?

---

## UPDATE:

I found a way to do it.

Since I am using Windows 11, I found out that when doing "WIN + ." on my keyboard not only the emote menu would show up, but also a symbol menu.

[symbol menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NWDi.png)

Answer (score 0):

The character you're looking for is Unicode "Subscript Two", `U+2082`.

How to insert it in your document is dependent on the application you use, your OS, etc.: read documentation.